# Verb + same verb+ing

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

- I keep keeping my head raised when I walk.
- I find finding a chest of gold a lucky find.
- I know knowing English helps in life.
- I guess guessing right answers in a test won't help you much.
- I think thinking about it is silly.

Are they verb+gerund or what? How come they are grammatical?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's the same verb? Can you think of examples with different verbs that fill the same *slots*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All of these examples have complex gerund objects. The fact that the gerund is the same base as the verb doesn't matter at all.